# Is my proof correct for $\tanh{(\tau+\epsilon)}=\tanh{(\tau)}+\epsilon(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

I am trying to prove an equality using Mean Value Theorem, I wish to know if my reasoning is correct, or if someone can improve upon the proof. The expression I am trying to prove is:
\begin{equation}
\tanh{(\tau+\epsilon)}=\tanh{(\tau)}+\epsilon(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})
\end{equation}
where, $0\leq \zeta \leq \tau$.
My proof:
\begin{equation}
\tanh{(\tau+\epsilon)}=\int_0^{\tau+\epsilon}(1-\tanh^2{x})dx
\end{equation}, and
Using the MVT, the RHS of equation above, can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^{\tau+\epsilon}(1-\tanh^2{x})dx&=(\tau+\epsilon)(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})\\
&=\tau(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})+\epsilon(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})
\end{split}
\end{equation}. 
where $0\leq \zeta \leq \tau+\epsilon$
. Now, 
\begin{equation}
(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})=\frac{d(\tanh{x})}{dx}\Big|_\zeta
\end{equation},
Now, using the derivative version of the MVT on the RHS of equation above, one gets:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d(\tanh{x})}{dx}\Big|_\zeta=\frac{\tanh{(\tau})-0}{\tau-0}
\end{equation}.
Under the assumption, $0\leq \zeta\leq  \tau$.
Using all the above, it becomes, 
\begin{equation}
\tanh{(\tau+\epsilon)}=\tanh{(\tau)}+\epsilon(1-\tanh^2{\zeta})
\end{equation}.
Is my proof correct? Please comment! Thanks for your time and consideration!

Comment: How do you justify using the same $\zeta$ in both applications of the MVT?

Comment: You obtained some $0\leq \zeta _1\leq\tau +\varepsilon$ and $0\leq \zeta _2 \leq\tau$. Do you claim they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is more immediate. By MVT, for some $\zeta \in (\tau,\tau +\varepsilon)$
$$\frac{\tanh (\tau + \varepsilon) - \tanh (\tau)}{\varepsilon} = \tanh '(\zeta) = 1-\tanh ^2 (\zeta) $$
I am not sure how we were supposed to pick a suitable $0\leq \zeta\leq\tau$, however. In fact, I'm quite sure you won't be able to do that. For a sufficiently large $n = n(\varepsilon)$
$$\varepsilon > \tanh (n+1) - \tanh (n) = 1-\tanh ^2(\zeta) \geq 1 - \tanh (\zeta) $$
yielding $\tanh (\zeta) + \varepsilon >1$. If $\varepsilon >0$ is small, then no $0\leq \zeta\leq n$ would satisfy that demand.